# How to Do the total web form in disable mode

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am having web Page which consist of 130 `Drop downs` and 100 `Check Box list`. Total no of lines are 7500. This page is used for only user `VIEW` by receiving a `Query String` from an other Page. I starting each and every `control.enable = false` but taking much time. how to do it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to disable the controls from the code behind or in JavaScript? Which is your preferred way?

Comment: @JamieBabineau if he didn't specifyied JavaScript tag, I think it will be performed with the help of an asynchronous call to C#. Also, Take a look at this [method to find every kind of component in ASP.NET/C#](http://programcsharp.com/blog/post/Recursively-find-controls-by-type-with-generics) which might inspire you.

Comment: I preferred which is the best way according to you, that only

Comment: A tear shed for the poor users that will have to use 130 drop downs and 100 checkboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that it is not possible to make whole form disable once i.e form does't have attribute disabled. You can go for the below function and call the function on body onLoad.

```
function disable() {
    var limit = document.forms[0].elements.length;
    for (i=0;i<limit;i++) {
      document.forms[0].elements[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any Namespace to be used for this function?

Comment: Did you add onLoad="disable" to the body tag?

Comment: Ya added now.. and where should i add this above function

Comment: end of the body or the head

Comment: are you hitting the disable method? Add "debugger;" to the first line of disable and view browser in dev tools. If you are calling it you should see it hit this line.

Comment: Remember to remove the debugger; line, Might have been a cacheing issue.

Comment: `btnEdit.Enabled = true;
            btnBack.Enabled = true;
            btnExport.Enabled = true;
            btnPrint.Enabled = true;` These fields are also gone into disable mode.. how to enable these

Comment: @Vikram : the above function will disabled the all component in the current page form.If you want some component like some button try to place them outside the form .

Comment: It it designed in side the form.. if put outside the form lot of changes i need to change.. any alternate please

Comment: @vikram: you can also do like this if you have limited # controls.After that function call,you can code for make enable the required component.Like $(selector).attr('disabled',false).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net controls, Use below code to disable at server side itself. Asp.net button, textbox, label... etc are derived from WebControl and DropDownList, CheckboxList are derived from ListControl.

```
foreach (var control in form1.Controls)
    {
        if (control is WebControl)
        {
            (control as WebControl).Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (control is ListControl)
        {
            (control as ListControl).Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (control is HtmlInputControl)
        {
            (control as HtmlInputControl).Disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Client code to disable all controls except buttons:

```
 function disableAllExceptButtons() {
        var limit = document.forms[0].elements.length;
        for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            var control = document.forms[0].elements[i];
            if (control.type != "button" && control.type != "submit") {
                control.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wrote this in function and call it in page load.. not working

Comment: are you using html  controls are asp.net controls?

Comment: Add Umar Memon's solution to body tag as follows <body onload="disable()">. Its working fine.

Comment: `btnEdit.Enabled = true; btnBack.Enabled = true; btnExport.Enabled = true; btnPrint.Enabled = true`; These fields are also gone into disable mode.. how to enable these

Comment: Try this code.   function disableAllExceptButtons() {
            var limit = document.forms[0].elements.length;
            for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                var control = document.forms[0].elements[i];
                if (control.type != "button") {
                    control.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: still Buttons are disabled

Comment: copy the button element code. I want to see how you created your button. is it using <input type="button"> or <input type="submit">?

Comment: if you use submit type buttons, use  if (control.type != "button" && control.type != "submit")  condition as shown in the above answer.

Comment: Now the button is enabled, but the functionality not working.`<div class="ButtonArea">
                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClick="btnBack_Click" />
            </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, on ready event

```
 var elem = $(input);
 $.each( elem , function() {
   $(this).attr('disabled', true);
 });
```

Using C#

```
void DisableAllControls(Control ctrl) {
    foreach(Control c in ctrl.Controls) {
        if (c is TextBox) {
            ((TextBox)(c)).Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (c is DropDownList) {
            ((DropDownList)(c)).Enabled = false;
        }
        // and so on............
        DisableControls(c);
    }
}
```

call it like `DisableAllControls(Page)` on page load event.

Comment: added c# version for you

Comment: not working. Iterating it in loop but functionality not working